# javascript/jquery scope has me stumped

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have wrapped a common ajax call into a function. It pings a script, returns JSON.

However for the life of me I can't seem to be able to have the JSON object be the return value of the function.

Must be something fairly simple I am missing, bu for the life of me can't work it out.

```
function queryCostCenter(user_id, currency_id, country_id){

   var output = null;
   var destinations = new Array();

   var destination = { qty:1, country: country_id };
   destinations.push(destination)           


   var data = {
                 destinations : $.toJSON(destinations),
                 user_id : user_id,
                 currency_id: currency_id
              };

   $.ajax({
         data: data,
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/lib/ajax/ajax_prepaid_cost_calculator.php',
         success: function(data) {         
            output = data;
            alert(output);
         }
   });

   alert(output);

   return json;

}
```

The alert() inside the ajax() call displays the json object, however if try and alert outside the function, and/or return the response from inside the ajax() call its value is null?!

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of [Return value from function with an Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562412/return-value-from-function-with-an-ajax-call), [Function inside jquery returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504950/function-inside-jquery-returns-undefined), [Javascript AJAX function returns undefined instead of true / false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813974/javascript-ajax-function-returns-undefined-instead-of-true-false), ...

Comment: [Returning data from jQuery ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168911/returning-data-from-jquery-ajax-request), [How can I get returning data from jquery ajax request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902043/how-can-i-get-returning-data-from-jquery-ajax-request), [jquery ajax callback out of the function scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691972/jquery-ajax-callback-out-of-the-function-scope), [return from jquery ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844832/return-from-jquery-ajax-call)...

Answer (score 9):

Typical mistake. The code after the Ajax call

```
alert(output);
return json;
```

is executed, *before* the Ajax call returns. It is **asynchronous** (meaning, it is not executed when and where you put it in the code, but at some later point in time). You can provide a callback to your function, like so:

```
// cb is our callback - it is a function
function queryCostCenter(user_id, currency_id, country_id, cb){ 
   var destinations = new Array();

   var destination = { qty:1, country: country_id };
   destinations.push(destination)           

   var data = {
                 destinations : $.toJSON(destinations),
                 user_id : user_id,
                 currency_id: currency_id
              };

   $.ajax({
         data: data,
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/lib/ajax/ajax_prepaid_cost_calculator.php',
         success: function(result) { // or just `success: cb`
            cb(result); // execute the callback with the returned data
         }
   });   
}
```

then:

```
queryCostCenter(some_value, some_value, some_value, function(result) {
    // do something with the returned data.
});
```

Or put all the logic in the success handler of the Ajax call. But with a callback function, you are more flexible and you can better reuse the function.

---

This a very common use case for callbacks. As you don't know *when* the Ajax call will be finished, you pass a function to the Ajax call that should be run, when some results is returned. Your are doing nothing else with the `success` handler: It is a function that is called when the call is finished.

Comment: You should mention the 'async' option.

Comment: I'll mention it. If you set the 'async' option to false, then the script will halt until the request is finished. Add `async: false,` above where you have `data: data` and your code works as is. Here's some reading. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @sje397: Honestly, I think the `async` option is nonsense. I did not do any measurements, but I cannot imagine that an Ajax request will be finished within 100ms (which is the maximum time a piece of code should run, otherwise the UI will seem to be slow for the user). There *might* be situations, where this option has an advantage. But the whole point of an Ajax request is to be asynchronous. For new developers in this area, the `async` might be tempting to use, because they don't know better... I would try to avoid it.

Comment: King: I totally agree - that's the sort of mention I was thinking of. Since it's easy to find in the docs, it's worth talking about I think. I've never had cause to use it. Though it does 'make the code work' in this case, it's a much better option to refactor the code to use a callback as you've shown.

Answer (score 2):

$.ajax() is async.
In short: the alert(output) outside your function block will most likely be called before the async method returned any result, therefor is still null.

Comment: @danlefree You can upvote all the correct answers if you want, not just the first one. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of scope. It's the asynchronous nature of your Ajax call. Your `queryCostCenter` function will likely return before the Ajax `success` handler runs. You need to kick off *all* post-Ajax logic in your `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't actually fetching and converting back to JSON, just a big text blob. look at the documentation for getJSON, which is what you need to use.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON({
     '/lib/ajax/ajax_prepaid_cost_calculator.php',
     {data:data}
     , function(data) {   
        alert(data.jsonElement);
        //do something with your data HERE

     }
```

});

with jsonElement being an element in your JSON array